# Find values across SQL SELECT statements so that the concatenation of any 2 values from each SELECT statement is below a certain max length?

Tags: mysql

I have a complex problem that I am not quite sure how to address.

I am defining two subset of values from the same table that match certain criteria.

**statement 1:**

```
SELECT value FROM Values WHERE category = a
```

**statement 2:**

```
SELECT value FROM Values WHERE category = b
```

But I also have an additional constraint which is that any value from the statement 1 concatenated with any value of statement 2 should result in a string whose length should be equal to or smaller than a given max string length.

What kind of query can I write to do this?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Lothaire

Edit:

My data looks like:

```
+---+---------+------------+----------+  
|id | routeId |category    | value    |  
+---+---------+------------+----------+  
| 1 | 1       |origin      | Paris    |  
| 2 | 1       |destination | New York |  
| 3 | 2       |origin      | Paris    |  
| 4 | 2       |destination | Berlin   |  
+------+--------------+---------------+
```

And I'd like to receive a list of routeId's for routes where origin.destination is less than n characters.

Now that I am looking at this problem more carefully, I see that my initial approach was incorrect, as I wrote that any value from the first select statement concatenated with any value from the second select statement should have a length under a certain character limit.
In fact, the problem is more complex, because the routeId for the origin value and the destination value should be the same for the pair of value whose concatenation should be under a max length.

Comment: How do you want the values returned? Could you perhaps provide some sample data and expected result?

Comment: Will there ever be more than one origin and destination per `routeID`?

Comment: Do you want to compare the concatenation of the `origin` value of each `routeID` to the `destination` value of EVERY `routeID` in the table?

Comment: no, only one origin and destination per routeId. But there might be other attributes, which I don't care about for the purpose of this example (such as travel time, price...).

And no, like you suggest, I don't want to compare the concatenation of any route origin with any route destination. What I actually want to do is find the routeId's for the routes whose origin and destination concatenated together is below a certain string length. For instance, in the example above, with a max string length of 11, the query should return only routeId 2.

Comment: So basically if a particular `routeID`'s origin value concatenated with its `destination` value is longer than n characters, then don't show that particular `routeID`. So if the max chars was 12, `routeID` 1 would be filtered out because `ParisNew York` is 13 characters, but `routeID` 2 would show because `ParisBerlin` is only 11 characters. This is what my first solution does.

Comment: Thank you so much Zane! I'll try it tonight and let you know, but reading your query, it looks like it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT a.routeID
FROM   tbl a
JOIN   tbl b ON a.routeID = b.routeID AND b.category = 'destination'
WHERE  a.category = 'origin' AND
       CHAR_LENGTH(CONCAT(a.value, b.value)) <= 5
```

Where `tbl` is the name of your table, and `5` is the maximum length of the concatenation of the two statements. This compares the concatenation of each `routeID`'s origin value to its destination value. If it's longer than five characters, then the `routeID` is filtered out.

---

Or perhaps this is what you want:

Comparing the concatenation of the `origin` value of each `routeID` to EVERY `destination` value in the table:

```
SELECT     a.routeID
FROM       tbl a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT value FROM tbl WHERE category='destination') b
WHERE      a.category = 'origin'
GROUP BY   a.routeID
HAVING     MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(CONCAT(a.value, b.value))) <= 5
```

Comment: That looks like it. I will test this tonight and let you know. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @LothaireRuellan try my updated solution. This is assuming there is only one 'origin' and 'destination' for every distinct `routeID`.

Comment: Thanks Zane. Your solution indeed worked. Here's the query I am using, based on your example. `SELECT a.memberId, a.value1, b.value2
    FROM  ( SELECT memberId, value FROM  catalog_member_variable_value WHERE variableId = $variableId1 AND languageId = 1 AND catalogId = $catalogId ) a
    JOIN   ( SELECT memberId, value FROM  catalog_member_variable_value WHERE variableId = $variableId2  AND languageId = 1 AND catalogId = $catalogId) b
    ON a.memberId = b.memberId
    WHERE  CHAR_LENGTH(CONCAT(a.value1, b.value2)) <= $maxlength`

Answer (score 0):

You may try this query:

```
SELECT t1.value AS v1, t2.value AS v2, LEFT(CONCAT(t1.value, t2.value), 20) AS my_text
FROM `values` t1, `values` t2
WHERE t1.category=a AND t2.category=b
```

I used a maximum length of 20 characters, change it as you need.

Since VALUES is a [reserved word in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), it must be enclosed in backticks to avoid syntax errors.

Other query, after reading your comment:

```
SELECT t1.value AS v1, t2.value AS v2, CONCAT(t1.value, t2.value) AS my_text
FROM `values` t1, `values` t2
WHERE t1.category=a AND t2.category=b
AND CHAR_LENGTH(CONCAT(t1.value, t2.value))<=20
```

This query will return records whose concatenation of both values is shorter or equal to 20 characters.

Documentation: [LENGTH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length) and [CHAR_LENGTH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length)

Comment: Hi Jocelyn. Thank you for your reply. I'll try your suggestion tonight, but reading your query, it looks like it will give me a column with the concatenation of t1.value and t2.value truncated at 20 characters. My constraint is that any full value from t1 concatenated with any full value from t2 should be below a certain max length. Maybe I can add a condition along the lines of `WHERE LENGTH(CONCAT(t1.value,t2.value)) <= 20` ?